# Problems with Kontakt.io Beacon example

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I have recently acquired a beacon from Kontakt.io

I followed the "Monitoring code example" from here: http://docs.kontakt.io/android-sdk/quickstart/#monitoring-code-sample

The Kontakt library is included (since other methods from the library is working), but the following line is giving me an error:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoring(Region.EVERYWHERE);
```

Error:

```
startMonitoring (java.util.Set<com.kontakt.sdk.android.device.Region>) in BeaconManager
cannot be applied to (com.kontakt.sdk.android.device.Region)
```

I have also tried creating a new region with the proximity uuid from the beacon:

```
static UUID uid = UUID.fromString("1DEFF9522D014664BB6088F065302B83");
private static final Region beacon = new Region(uid, 49668, 35726, null);
```

but this throws the same error.

I'm quite new to java and this might be a fairly simple question, but how do i resolve this?

Comment: It looks like it expects a set of regions, not a single region.  Try creating a set and adding your single region to it.

Comment: Tried creating a HasdSet and adding the Region.EVERYWHERE constant to it: Set<Region> regSet = new HashSet<Region>(); regSet.add(Region.EVERYWHERE); Android Studio now accepts it as the right type, however I get a fatal error saying that the Venue set is empty or null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the changelog on their website you will see that there is new version of API. Clearly example is not updated. If you want to monitor `Region.EVERYWHERE` you can simply call `beaconManager.startMonitoring()` according to [docs](http://docs.kontakt.io/android-sdk/javadoc/index.html) it should work.